# How do I combine multiple squares into one Tetris block?

Tags: physics, software-engineering, phaser

I am learning [Phaser](http://phaser.io/) by making a simple game—[Tetris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris). I'm having difficulties:

1. Can I use simple rectangles as [tetrominoes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino) or they should be sprites? I don't know how make the figure's block from simple rectangles and apply physics to it.
2. How I can join 4 separate squares into one tetromino?

Comment: Did you try asking on the Phaser forums? (Do they even have forums?)

Comment: yes. I have create a topic there but my post was not approved yet. It seems strange. It takes a long time to get an approve on these forum. I am still awaiting answer there.

Comment: It's probably to prevent spam. Your question is pretty broad for this site; can you edit your question to include what you already tried, and what specific problem(s) you ran into?

Comment: http://www.photonstorm.com/phaser/tutorial-making-your-first-phaser-game Doesn't have too much to do with tetris, but I does go over the basics for Phaser.